# Foreign Key MySQL - Moodle

Tags: sql, moodle

i have a table, Categories, it has a column 'id' (PK) and the same table has the column parent which is a FK.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPB6e.png)

What i need (and can't) is to take the 'parent' id and show the value 'name' associated  to this id, when i select 'name' it doesn't show me 'parent' name but 'id' name.

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykb9m.png)

Please let me know if the information is enough.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you mean write a SQL query to show this information?

Comment: That's right Nick, i wanted query the database. Russell answer worked!
Thanks your for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename,
    cat.id AS catid, cat.name AS catname,
    cat.parent AS parentcatid,
    CASE
        WHEN cat.parent = 0 THEN 'Root Category'
        ELSE parentcat.name
    END AS parentcatname
FROM mdl_course c
JOIN mdl_course_categories cat ON cat.id = c.category
LEFT JOIN mdl_course_categories parentcat ON parentcat.id = cat.parent
```

Comment: Super, would you mind marking the answer as correct? :)

Comment: Done! (I didn't know I should marked the correct answer, thanks again)